# Solve the equation $\frac{7x^2 - x + 4}{\sqrt{3x^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - x} - x\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} = 2\sqrt 2$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Solve the equation $\dfrac{7x^2 - x + 4}{\sqrt{3x^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - x} - x\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} = 2\sqrt 2$ over the reals.

Remember when I posted a question almost identical to this one?

Well, turned out my teacher actually mistyped the question. But even when the problem is correctly typed, we couldn't still figure it out throughout the lesson. (And remember the solution must be able to be executed in a test setting.)

Comment: "This one" question does not exist.

Comment: Oh, I thought that deleted question would show up at others' computer screens besides mine. Sorry about that.

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt FYI, note that deleted posts, apart from the person who wrote the question and anybody who answered the question, will (as far as I know) only be shown to users with a reputation of at least $10,000$.

Comment: It would be nice if you could tell me what text book are you using and at what educational level are you exposed to such a complex equation?

Comment: It is something I called "my teacher's homework". And I am a (gifted) 9th-grade student, although I wouldn't consider myself to be one, I've got so much more to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Bunyakovsky and AM - GM inequalities for $(\sqrt{3x^2 - 1}, \sqrt{x^2 - x}, \sqrt{x^2 + 1})$, $(1, 1, -x)$ and $(2x^2 + 4)$, $(5x^2 - x)$, we have that $$(\sqrt{3x^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - x} - x\sqrt{x^2 + 1})^2 \le (1 + 1 + x^2)(3x^2 - 1 + x^2 - x + x^2 + 1)$$

$$ = (x^2 + 2)(5x^2 - x) = \dfrac{(2x^2 + 4)(5x^2 - x)}{2} \le \dfrac{(7x^2 - x + 4)^2}{8}$$

The equality sign occurs when $\sqrt{3x^2 - 1} = \sqrt{x^2 - x} = -\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x}$ and $2x^2 + 4 = 5x^2 - x$.

From the second condition, we have that $3x^2 - x - 4 = 0 \implies \left [ \begin{align} x &= -1\\ x &= \dfrac{4}{3} \end{align} \right.$.

Plugging in $x = -1$, we have that $\sqrt{3x^2 - 1} - \sqrt{x^2 - x} = \sqrt{3 \cdot 1^2 - 1} - \sqrt{1^2 + 1} = 0$.

And $-\dfrac{2\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x} - \sqrt{3x^2 - 1} = \dfrac{2\sqrt{1^2 + 1}}{1} - \sqrt{3 \cdot 1^2 - 1} = 0$

Plugging in $x = \dfrac{4}{3}$, we have that $\sqrt{3x^2 - 1} - \sqrt{x^2 - x} = \sqrt{3 \cdot \left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^2 - 1} - \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^2 - \dfrac{4}{3}} \ne 0$.

So $x = -1$.

Comment: I would suggest you to explain in details the inequalities in the first two lines.

Comment: A comment on edit: I would assume that a) there is no separate Bunyakovsky inequality, there is Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality (in fact you use it in the simple Cauchy form); b) the second inequality is the A.M.-G.M. one. Please correct me if it is not the case.

Comment: Inequality names are really confusing and it differs around the world. So sorry about that.

Comment: As the working language of this site is English, probably the English terms should be used also for inequalities. One suggestion more: it is not enough to demonstrate  $\sqrt{3x^2 - 1} = \sqrt{x^2 - x}$, you need (as you correctly stated before) $\sqrt{3x^2 - 1} = \sqrt{x^2 - x} = -\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x}$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Let me fix the answer.